# How to use MFC ListCtrl in SDI

Tags: mfc, clistctrl, sdi

I am really a beginner with MFC. I just want a few guidelines on how to use a ListCtrl in an SDI application. For example, getting input from the user and displaying it in the listctrl when a button is clicked. Please guide me.

Comment: You must be more specific, otherwise your question will likely be closed very soon.

Comment: I know how to implement ListCtrl in Dialog based applications. But I don't know how to implement it in SDI application. Pls guide on the steps to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

In SDI application I would use `CListView`-derived class for main view. This class has been designed to be used in SDI/MDI apps and supports standard MFC document-view architecture. The `CListView` class internally uses CListCtrl, but it does automatic resizing and other handy things, you can also get direct access to embedded list ctrl by calling `CListView::GetListCtrl()` method that returns `CListCtrl*`.